# Cache data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, express, mlab

I am trying to make my own blogging system using node.js, express.js with jade and mongodb (hosted on mongolab.com). I want to have on one page list of all posts stored in database. I have worries about page load speed after I add more posts cause I am contacting mongodb each time page refreshes.

My questions are: Is it ok to get data from database each time page refreshes? Or how can I store these data cached somewhere? Or is there a quicker way because these data are not often changed?

Comment: These answers, especially to question 1, depend a lot on the requirements of your webpage/app. The big one being, How often is the page going to be refreshed? If this is a site with 100 concurrent users, caching would be less important than if there are 10000. Are there speeds requirements for page load time?

Comment: MongoDB does in-memory caching of the most recently requested documents by itself. But when you have a high latency to the database, caching on node.js might save you some ms of pageload latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding query caching on MongoDB, the official documentation says:

> MongoDB keeps most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.
>
> MongoDB does not cache the query results in order to return the cached results for identical queries.

So, depending on your workload and your hardware resources, you may have a high hit ratio for some queries as a consequence of the first sentence above.

However, consider having a cache layer in front of your site, like a CDN or even some basic caching with Nginx or Varnish. In my opinion, this would be the right solution for you, instead of relying only on the database.